# Magento missing translation

Tags: magento, zend-framework, magento-1.9

This is a very simple question: What do I need to change in order to translate this?? Is it hard-coded somewhere? Inside database?

The code bellow creates this tabs and can be found at this file `app\design\frontend\rwd\default\template\catalog\product\view.phtml@175`:

```
<div class="product-collateral toggle-content tabs">
    <?php if ($detailedInfoGroup = $this->getChildGroup('detailed_info', 'getChildHtml')):?>
        <dl id="collateral-tabs" class="collateral-tabs">
            <?php foreach ($detailedInfoGroup as $alias => $html):?>
                <dt class="tab"><span><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getChildData($alias, 'title')) ?></span></dt>
                <dd class="tab-container">
                    <div class="tab-content"><?php echo $html ?></div>
                </dd>
            <?php endforeach;?>
        </dl>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

[image]

It does not follow the `$this->__('Recurring Profile')` pattern. My `app/locale/pt_BR/Mage_Sales.csv` already have the key/value `"Recurring Profiles","Perfis Recorrentes"`.

This is the page of a recurring profile product running in a Magento 1.9 instance.

Comment: Also ensure that the text in the template is wrapped in a localisation call

Comment: @scrowler it seems the template does not use the localization call :/ Any suggestion?

Comment: Wrap in <?php echo $this->__('text here')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @scrowler. Magento is missing the proper localization method call. The code at `app\design\frontend\rwd\default\template\catalog\product\view.phtml@175` should be changed to:

```
<div class="product-collateral toggle-content tabs">
    <?php if ($detailedInfoGroup = $this->getChildGroup('detailed_info', 'getChildHtml')):?>
        <dl id="collateral-tabs" class="collateral-tabs">
            <?php foreach ($detailedInfoGroup as $alias => $html):?>
                <dt class="tab"><span><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->__( $this->getChildData($alias, 'title'))) ?></span></dt>
                <dd class="tab-container">
                    <div class="tab-content"><?php echo $html ?></div>
                </dd>
            <?php endforeach;?>
        </dl>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Just added the `$this->__(...)` and check for proper localization in .csv files.

Answer (score 0):

Look up to 
app/locale/pt_BR/Mage_Sales.csv
There would be something like 
"Recurring Profiles","Perfiles Repetitivos"

If the file doesnt exists, copy the one from app/locale/en_US/Mage_Sales.csv and replace with your desired translations.

Comment: tks for your comment, but it seems your suggestion does not fix the problem. I've added more comments in the question.